# Given the Power Spectral Density of a random process determin if it is stationary in a wide sense

Tags: power-spectral-density

I am studying a Communication Systems course and have trouble figuring out how to tell and prove if a random process is stationary in a wide sense while only having it's power spectral density.

some examples of the problems I am tackling are,

S(f) = sin2πf/(2πf)

S(f) = cos(2πf)^2

S(f) = (cos2πf)^2

The only thing I understand proves a Random Process is stationary in a wide sense is that it's autocorralation function is subject only to the time shift τ and not time, but I haven't seen any rules on how it can be determined from the Power Spectral Density.

Comment: Your first example is _not_ a valid power spectral density at all since it takes on positive and negative values, whereas a valid PSD must have nonnegative value at all frequencies. Ditto the second if what you mean is $\cos((2\pi f)^2) = \cos(4\pi^2 f^2)$.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thank you very much. If the first was S(f) = (sin2πf/(2πf))^2 which would make it only have positive values, would it still be illegible of being a PSD for a wide sense stationary Random Process due to S(0) that is supposed to be the area of the autocorration function not being computable?